# KMM generics in Swift: force KMM Any to be Swift Any instead of AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, generics, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm currently working on a KMM library that is implemented in Swift.
So there's something I don't really get with generics.

I have my KMM generic class:

```kotlin
class Foo<T> {
 ...
}
```

Then, i can use it without any problem in KMM, for example like that

```kotlin
var bar = Foo<List<SomeClass>>()
```

### The original problem:

This is a little different when I use it in swift, cause when I compile my KMM lib as a Swift Framework, my class is now declared this way:

```swift
public class Foo<T> : KotlinBase where T : AnyObject {
 ...
}
```

And here, I cannot use it with Arrays as I do in KMM because a Swift Array is not Any but AnyObject. For example:

```swift
var bar = Foo<[SomeClass]>()
```

and then i got the error:

> 'Foo' requires that '[AnyObject]' be a class type

### Question:

Is it possible to force something so that KMM Any is interpreted in Swift as Any and not AnyObject, or is there another solution to this problem ?

## EDIT:

As [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander) said:

> There's probably no way to work around this. Fundamentally, the JVM
> lacks a way to express in-place allocated value types like Swift's
> structs or enums, besides the handful of primitives that are
> hardcoded into the platform.

So I tried to make an overload of Foo in KMM like that:

```kotlin
class ListFoo<T>() : Foo<T>() where T: List<Any> {}
```

and then compile it as Swift Framework (I set Foo as open class btw).

So I was expecting that my ListFoo class in Swift looked like something like that:

```swift
public class ListFoo<T> : Foo<T> where T : [Any] {
  public init()
}
```

But I the class I found was something more... well annoying:

```swift
 public class ListFoo<T> : Foo<NSArray> where T : AnyObject {
  public init()
}
```

Then I made some tests, and I believe that it doesn't matter what type I set for T in my KMM code, T is **ALWAYS** considered as `AnyObject` in the Swift Framework.

### The final questions:

- Is there any way to make the compiler understand which type we want for our Generic Type in `Swift` like `Arrays`?
- Is it a KMM issue or a normal issue ?
- Am I just using generic classes the wrong way ?

Comment: There's probably no way to work around this. Fundamentally, the JVM lacks a way to express in-place allocated value types like Swift's structs or enums, besides the handful of primitives that arer hardcoded into the platform.

Comment: @Alexander So, should I declare antoher generic class named something like `class ArrayFoo<T: List<Any>>` specificaly for swift arrays ?

Comment: Seeing Alexander's comment, I realised I brainfarted there. I thought it had something to do with `T` being nullable, which doesn't make sense at all when I think about it now. I agree with Alexander - this is probably not possible. Worst case scenario: you have to use `NSArray`.

Comment: @Sweeper unfortunately, when i tried with NSArray i got this error: `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSArray'` and XCode didn't find my class constructor

Comment: Exactly, `NSArray` isn't generic, hence "worst case scenario".

Comment: If you `import Foundation`, Array will become bridgable to `AnyObject` (IIRC). Most other structs, too, they'll be wrapped in an object of `_SwiftValue`.

Comment: @Alexander It is bridgeable, but not in generic constraints, I don't think.

Comment: True, that gets lost.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, report this as a bug? To me this looks like a KMM bug. I mean you are not specifying anything in your Kotlin class but the generator decides to constraint it to a class.

Comment: Well actually I did not know how to do. The only thing i did was creating a post on the kotlin forum: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kmm-generics-in-swift-force-kmm-any-to-be-swift-any-instead-of-anyobject/22140